# Can a variable in main function be access outside the main?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo();
int main()
{
    int b = 0;
    int a[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    foo();
    return 0;
}

void foo()
{
    //write some code to print a and b
}
```

My Question is:

How to get the local variable from outside without pass any parameter ?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to avoid passing them as parameters, if you want to print their values?

Comment: I think maybe the local variable could be accessed by operating stack.I want to know the principle of how a program running.

Comment: It's best to not learn such principles as this.

Comment: @Codert, when you pass them as parameters, that is exactly what happens. The compiler generates code to push them on to the stack in the calling function and access them in the called function. You can see these details in the assembly code generated by the compiler.

Comment: @Ramana，thanks , I will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible. You need to pass a pointer to it to access it from a function or make it global.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two global variables and store each the values of a and b in them. In the `foo()` create two variables a and b and store values of ga and gb

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo();
int gb,ga[6];
int main()
{
    int b = 0;
    int a[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    gb=b;
    for (int x = 0 ; x<6 ; x++)
       ga[x]=a[x];
    foo();
    return 0;
}
void foo()
{
    int a=ga;
    int b[6];
    for (int x = 0 ; x<6 ; x++)
      b[x]=gb[x];
    //now you can use a and b here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a global pointer,and inside main,assign the address of the local variabe to that pointer,and use it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No we cant. We can make public class or even another function. As we are defining it in the main, we can't.